# Modifying a crossdomain XML policy to accept null origin headers

Tags: xml, ember.js, cross-domain, access-control

I am currently dealing with an error that reads

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

The request is working fine on my server, but breaks on my client. I recently found this file, `public/crossdomain.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <!-- Read this: www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html -->

  <!-- Most restrictive policy: -->
  <!-- <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="none"/> -->

  <!-- Least restrictive policy: -->

  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>

</cross-domain-policy>
```

While this looks like the fix I have been seeking, I am still being thrown the same error. There are no issues like this server side, and my client now largely matches the configuration of my server. Why would this policy fail to resolve the error? Do I need to configure this policy further to accept the required headers?

UPDATE: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWcRe.jpg) is a rundown of the client side errors and the server output when I try to make the cross domain request

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is to modify your server to respond to the preflight `HEAD` request with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. This is a browser security feature, you can't modify it from your client website. You have to configure this on your server.

Also verify how you access your client. The origin should be a valid domain.

Understand the same-origin policy and CORS. Do you really want to make a CORS request, or not? If not, use the ember dev server proxy.

Comment: My server is actually able to handle the request: it goes to the auth landing page (coinbase in this case) and hangs because it's waiting for a client side response that won't come. Another strange error is that, when I try to use an ember proxy server, it still breaks down, saying that the origin of my local host is null. I'm considering trying to just hard reset my dev environment and see if that does any good, but beyond that, I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you verify that the server responses to the Head request? With what headers?

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/Rig2V) is an album of the errors and the corresponding network requests on my client side when I try to make the call without running a proxy server (including the output of my server in the terminal). Is this what you were looking for?